# Exporting a picture or snapshot of a form to Powerpoint from Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, powerpoint

I want to be able to create a loop in Access VBA that basically opens up my form based on a parameter, takes a picture or copies the form somehow and then pastes that image into a Powerpoint deck.  The loop would then close the form, get the next parameter to open the same form with new data and do the same operation on the next slide of the Powerpoint deck.

I've googled this and cannot find anything that works for me. Thanks!

REVISION:

Since this seems to be a challenge to accomplish directly within Access, let me ask it another way.  I've tried to output the form to a PDF file through VBA

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "MYFORM", acFormatPDF, "MYPATH & MYFILENAME"
```

When I do this in a loop I only get the very last form that opens, as if when Access is sending each form to the PDF file it is overwriting the last one each time.  The other problem is that I need to output the form in landscape and I'm not sure how get this to happen in the PDF file.  Are there any settings that go with this method or code that would precede or follow it that would allow me to accomplish this?  This is alternative because I can then just manually convert the PDF to Powerpoint if I need to.

Comment: Some sort of [higher-level automation app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_macro_recorder_software) like AutoHotKey might be able to do it.

Comment: thanks Gord.  I'm trying to avoid introducing another variable, but I will check it out if there is no other solution.